# Make tMap remove a date 00/00/00

Tags: talend

I have a csv file which have sometime a date like this 00/00/00.
By using tMap, I want to make a condition: if the date is 00/00/00, make it null. 
I've tried but it's not working:

```
ToMap.date_naissance  != "00/00/00" ? (ToMap.date_naissance).toString() : null
```

Thank you

Comment: Hard to help without further information. Data type of date_naissance? Why the toString, what data type is the field you want to write into? What is the error you are getting?

Comment: its date of birth 
toString bcz i'll convert it after tMap
the datatype input to tMap String output String

Comment: I havant error but i have in the csv list of date of births and in this list there are some time like this 00/00/00 "just zero" i want to make it null

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand those comments and cannot help any further. Maybe a picture would be helpful. Or more output data. Maybe this also depends on your output method.

Comment: I want to say 
if (ToMap.date_naissance=="00/00/00")
{
ToMap.date_naissance==null
}

Answer (score 0):

As input is a csv file, you should consider date_naissance field as a string. Change it in the corresponding schema and try this:

ToMap.date_naissance.equals("00/00/00") ? null : date_naissance

For France it should be dd/MM/yy.

Hope this helps,
TRF